# Why does forward selection only take $O(p^2)$ calls to the learning algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, forward-backward

In http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes-all/cs229-notes5.pdf pg 5, it states that forward search takes $O(p^2)$ (note the notes uses $n$ instead of $p$ for the number if independent variables).

Isn't the number of calls actually $O(2^p \cdot k$)? You're consider all possible subsets of independent variables in forward search, of which there are $2^p$ of them. For each subset you perform a k-fold validation so $k$ learning calls for each subset.

How is it that it's quadratic instead of exponential?

Comment: +1 for the unusual question (at least on here) about time complexity, but please do note Andrew Gelman's stance on stepwise regression: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/06/02/hate-stepwise-regression/.

Comment: @Dave Wait, is forward selection a subset of stepwise regression?

Comment: Isn’t forward selection trying out your variables, getting the best fit with one, and then adding additional variables one at a time until the increase in fit isn’t worth adding a new variable (measured by any number of methods, AIC, for example)?

Comment: @Dave Yes, when I originally posted this and replied to you, I misunderstood forward selection. I had thought it was a method that tests ALL possible subsets instead of approaching it in a greedy fashion.

Comment: Like so many things in statistics, stepwise model selection is wrong in many ways, but can be extremely useful. I think sometimes the strong opinions of seasoned statisticians can scare off those new to the field from developing a broad toolset while learning the limitations of different methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the forward selection procedure described, the features are partitioned into selected vs. candidate sets. At the start, the selected set is empty, and all $p$ features are candidates. At each stage, each candidate feature is provisionally added as a(n additional) trial feature, and the best one is chosen to be kept.

So 1 new feature is removed from the candidate set after each iteration.
This means the first iteration tests $p$ candidates, the second $p-1$, etc.
And $p + (p-1) + \ldots + 2 + 1 = O[p^2]$.

Once a feature is added to the selected set, it is *never* removed in subsequent iterations. So the procedure does not explore *all* subsets of features. Rather it is a [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) heuristic, with no guarantees of optimality. (I believe this is why techniques like [LASSO](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lasso) have become more popular for feature selection.)

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood forward selection and the algorithm in the link I provided. Forward selection isn't the feature selection method that tests all possible subsets of the $p$ features? What is the name of the method that does?

Comment: @David I am not sure if there is a particular "method" for this. Some methods, like the LASSO path, allow feature selection considering all features together. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51010/lasso-vs-forward-selection/51014#51014) may be relevant.